# Need regex to separate the integer from the array to comma separated

Tags: arrays, regex, performance, jmeter

I am looking to have a regex for passing a value in the array to comma separated. Here is the regex I used for the fetching the value.

> Regex: id="selectedAgency(.+?)" currently using this regex I am able to find the below value which is matching in
>   id="selectedAgency[1]"

Hence the outcome I receives is as follows:

> &selectedAgencies=[14],[12],[10],[9]

However I would like to have the actual output as the below:

> &selectedAgencies= 14,12,10,9

Comment: @Pravitha V: Done.. Can you look into this concern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image] To remove [] use different regex:

```
 Regex : id="selectedAgency\[(\d+)
```

Comment: checked no match found.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this JavaScript version works for you but here it is. Hopefully the regex and replace part should help.

```
let str = "&selectedAgencies=[14],[12],[10],[9]";
let result = str.replace(/\[(\d+)\]/g, "$1");   //&selectedAgencies=14,12,10,9
```